# TextButton isPressed() not working

Tags: java, android, libgdx, scene2d

I am having problems with scene2d. I've programatically created a TextButton (without json file) and for some reason, isPressed() doesn't return true when I am pressing it. Not only that, but I set the downFontColor of my TextButtonStyle, but it doesn't do anything either. This is my first time using scene2d, so i'm still new. And I am testing on android.

I use a custom class that extends TextButton, which has nothing to do with the problems, it is just an empty class. Not to metsion I have tested it on a textbutton. Heres the classes :

MainMenu, where I create the Stage :

```
public MainMenu(Main main) {

    this.main = main;

    font_neutral = Tools.generateFont(Gdx.files.internal("Fonts/Android.ttf"), Color.WHITE, 150);

    initViewport();

    //Scene2D
    GlyphLayout glyphLayout = new GlyphLayout(); //Used for getting width/height of textButton. Set text, then get width

    TextButton.TextButtonStyle style = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
    style.font = font_neutral;
    style.fontColor = new Color(1, 1, 1, 1);
    style.downFontColor = new Color(40, 130, 100, 1);
    style.checkedFontColor = Color.BLUE;

    CustomTextButton button_play = new CustomTextButton("Play", style);
    glyphLayout.setText(style.font, "Play");
    float x = camera.viewportWidth / 3 - glyphLayout.width / 2;
    float y = camera.viewportHeight / 2 - glyphLayout.height / 2;
    button_play.setPosition(x, y);
    button_play.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);

    stage = new Stage(viewport);
    stage.addActor(button_play);
}

@Override
public void show() {

}

public void update(float delta) {

    stage.act(delta);


}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    update(delta);

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 0);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);

    stage.draw();

}
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Where exactly are you using `.isPressed()`? I don't see it in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Stage` is an `InputProcessor`, you need to tell LibGDX to listen to the `Stage`. Put `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage)` after initialising your `Stage`.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me again! These little things tend to get me

Comment: However, there is still a problem. The clicking works, but it seems that even if I change the color in the TextButtonStyle, it stays the color of the original font I set it to. So even if I set the TextButtonStyle.color, it will still only be black.

Comment: Interestingly enough, setting the colors for the style only works when I use a pre-made color (eg.. Color.GREEN), If I create a new Color(), it doesn't work. Very odd.

Comment: Ok, turns out when I create the color with a hex value, it works. Not sure why.

Comment: Glad I can help. `ImageTextButton` or any `Actor` that displays text uses a `BitmapFontCache`. I have also had trouble changing the color of a `BitmapFontCache` in the past and I am not sure what a solid solution is. You might be able to try `button.getLabel().setColor()` instead of resetting the whole style.

Comment: That didn't work. It is unfortunate because I don't exactly understand how this hex works. If I go online and get a hex value, and paste it into the Color constructor, it just gives me syntax errors.

Comment: I don't use hex, I always just set text color using rgba values, you can try converting your hex to rgba and set like `new Color(r, g, b, a)` (note these values are 0-1 so you might have to divide them by 255). Otherwise I just found this which could be relevant to your problem; https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Color-Markup-Language

Comment: That was my problem! I forgot that you had to divide by 255. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe look into my new question? :D